# How search for a file/folder by a string query in OS X?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Like Finder, you give it a string query and it returns a list of files with the matching string, I do not want to use the other method of getting all the files in a directory and then iterating it one by one for performance issues.

I looked in `FileManager` but there is nothing like that.

Comment: The Finder uses Spotlight (for example [NSMetadataQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmetadataquery))

Comment: Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: After some searching, using NSMetaDataQuery will not be useful in case of searching in not indexed and system directories. The best option I've found so far is to use find command, execute and get the results in the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vadian I got a hint:

Implemented the method after a bit googling, hope you find it useful.

Note: This method use spotlight searching, which can be faster than traditional methods, but it's limited to non-system and indexed directories.

After setting the predicate and paths, you listen for the notification triggered when it finishes gathering the results.

```
func getFiles(in paths: [String], query: String) {
    let queryMeta = NSMetadataQuery()
    let nf = NotificationCenter.default
    nf.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: nil, queue: operationQueue, using:{_ in
        queryMeta.disableUpdates()
        print(queryMeta.results.count)
        for item in queryMeta.results {
            if let itemMeta = item as? NSMetadataItem, let name = itemMeta.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemPathKey) {
                print(name)
            }
        }
    })
    queryMeta.searchScopes = paths
    queryMeta.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] '\(query)'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey)
    print("Starting searching for query: \(query)")
    queryMeta.start()
}
```